# Draw chart in pdf codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My requirement is to draw a pie chart and bar chart in a pdf.
So anyone can guide me in right direction that is there any library is available to draw chart in pdf..? or I want to create chart using google chart or mpdf api and then export to pdf..?

```
  Note:Technology used : PHP framework :codeigniter
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
You can use SVG graph library to generate graph and mpdf library to create pdf. You can print graph easily in pdf using mpdf library.
http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph-using.php
http://www.w3school.info/2016/02/08/convert-html-to-pdf-in-codeigniter-using-mpdf/